# Finish activity when user touch on outside of ImageView or any View

Tags: android, android-viewpager, imageview, activity-finish

I have an Activity whose theme is **Theme.AppCompat.Translucent**, that contains `View Pager` (Number of images shows in `ImageView`) using https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow

When the user clicks on the outside of the image I want to finish my activity.
I have no idea about it. Please help to solve it!!!

**My code is below**

**banner.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:coverflow="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#80000000"
        tools:context=".ActivityCoverflowBanner">

        <coverflowLibrary.FeatureCoverFlow
            android:id="@+id/coverflow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            coverflow:coverHeight="180dp"
            coverflow:coverWidth="150dp"
            coverflow:maxScaleFactor="1.5"
            coverflow:reflectionGap="-15px"
            coverflow:rotationThreshold="50"
            coverflow:scalingThreshold="0.9"
            coverflow:spacing="0.5" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

**item.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgBanner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@mipmap/demoimg" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/mProgressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/corner_radius_s"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtPackageName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/summary_button_margin"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="@color/BlueTextColor"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtViewMore"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/blackcurvedbutton"
                    android:padding="@dimen/card_margin_top"
                    android:text="@string/view_more"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<activity
                android:name=".ActivityCoverflowBanner"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_coverflow_banner"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
```

Comment: update your answer with xml file that have view pager.

Comment: I have updated my code!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You need to get the parent view (eg:- LinearLayout,Relative Layout or something) that holds the `ImageView` as a child or where you want to add click and finish.
if `banner.xml` is ur main xml. then put Listener on `RelativeLayout` or `FeatureCoverFlow` if it is on full screen.

**Second** 
set `onClickListener` on the parent view using `setOnClickListener(this)`.

**Third** 
apply as @Ricardo answered.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() != R.id.imgBanner)
        finish();
}
```

**OR**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.yourParentView)
        finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to achieve what you want. Just catch the event that is not a click on the ImageView

Set `OnClickListener` to your activity, after that, override the method `OnClick` and let anything do what you want if it is not the `ImageView`. Here is a short example how:

```
public class myActivity implements OnClickListener{

    ImageView myImageView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
        myImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    } 

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v != myImageView)
            finish(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but It's not working for me! I have Coverflow ViewPager and i have set on click event which you have mentioned above that i have set in adapter but it's not working.

Comment: but i think you should add the listener to parent view first. otherewise onClick will not get fired.

Comment: Mean? Can you explain in brief? or post your answer.